# Problem with force:auth:web:login

Tags: authentication, salesforcedx-cli

I have the following problem: when I try to use the `sfdx force:auth:web:login` command, nothing happens. When i do it with `sudo`, a salesforce site opens and I put in my login & password, the site then says that 'we can't connect to the server localhost'. Meanwhile in the terminal i get the following error

> Command failed with response.
>   (secret-tool:3754): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:52:24.080: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>       secret-tool: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=ce5e68462eef4ab6bb72802668bd136c --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1
>       . 
>   Try this:
>   Determine why this command failed to set an encryption key for user root: [/usr/bin/secret-tool store --label='salesforce.com' user local domain sfdx].

i tried googling it but with not much success. 
I'm using Manjaro Linux with KDE Plasma. 
I tried it on a freshly installed system (same) on a different machine, and got the same errors. 
I tried on a freshly installed system (Manjaro XFCE) on a different machine and it works.

So I would assume it has something to do with the KDE environment. I did install `gnome-keyring` because I saw that its absence can cause similar problems, but it didn't solve it for me.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: possible that the instance had not booted yet, have you re-triede since you got this error? is this repetitive? is this specific to 1 org you created? or reproduceable amongst all or most of them? if the problem persists, i would recommend contacting SF support

Comment: It did work with this org before on a different system (linux mint). 
I tried logging into a different org, but with the same result

Comment: Did you try what it suggests in the error message: _Try this: Determine why this command failed to set an encryption key for user root: `/usr/bin/secret-tool store --label='salesforce.com' user local domain sfdx`_

Comment: I tried to determine that but failed to do so. 

I ended up doing the same thing that I did on the other machine: reinstalling Manjaro with XFCE and then changing into KDE Plasma. 
It works

Answer (score 1):

I'm maintaining the `sfdx-cli` package on AUR for Arch, and have managed to reproduce this issue on a freshly installed system, albeit with GNOME instead of KDE.

In my case the issue is that Salesforce is bundling an old version of `xdg-open`, which calls executables that no longer exist on GNOME > 3.30. I am pretty certain that this also applies to KDE. You can try this [workaround](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/sfdx-cli/#news) proposed by one of the users:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/xdg-open /opt/sfdx-cli/node_modules/opn/vendor/xdg-open
```

That would replace the bundled version of `xdg-open` with the system `xdg-open`.
Afterwards the auth should work (please don't use `sudo` with it).

Comment: This should be fixed with the latest versions of GNOME, Arch kernel, and SFDX CLI.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the error is because you're running the process with sudo which in fact opens a new session and cannot therefore unlock the active user's keyring via dbus.